# Inheritance in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I am building a series of forms, and I am trying to inherit the functionality of a parent Form class into all the forms.  For example,

`LeaveForm extends Form` <sub><sup>(Model)</sup></sub>

`LeaveFormController extends FormController`

I am handling all the leave form specific stuff in `LeaveFormController` and `LeaveForm`.

In `LeaveFormController` constructor, I simply call the parent class constructor, then load the `LeaveForm` Model. And in `FormController` constructor, I load Form model.

My problem is, I get an error,

> Cannot redeclare class form in Form.php

Have I got my architecture wrong? How do I handle this ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/52848/) or [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56690/)? Also I would suggest making a new thread on the Codeigniter's forums

Answer (score 0):

check if the class has already been initialized like this:

```
if (!class_exists('classname'))
{
    // ok fine create new instance now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly when you `$this->load->model('Form')`, you manually `include`d the `models/form.php` file?

In your `leaveform.php` model file, make sure you load the superclass model you extend using codeigniter's model loading mechanism instead of `require` or `include`. Codeigniter has a loader that keeps track of already-loaded files to avoid redeclaring classes, but you need to use `$this->load` to use it. It won't know about files loaded directly with `include` or `require`.

So at the top of `leaveform.php`, use this:

```
$CI =& get_instance(); $CI->load->model('Form');
```

**This is not related,** but you will have pain unless you namespace your CodeIgniter model classes the same way you namespace Controller classes.

Try using `FormModel extends CI_Model {};` Instead of `Form extends CI_Model {};`